# Basic question: Difference between List.items and List.ItemCount in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, splistitem

Just for clarifying, I have written following two lines in Powershell script and see output as:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://intranet;

$list = $web.GetList("documents");
$items = $list.items;
```

i see these out puts in Powershell

```
$list.itemcount returns 56 but $items.count returns 23, why ?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**AS PER MSDN**

[SPList.ItemCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.itemcount(v=office.15).aspx):

The value of the ItemCount property includes folders within a document library, as well as files within subfolders. The value of the Count property of the SPListCollection class does not include folders.

[SPListItemCollection.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.count.aspx):

Gets the number of list items in the collection, excluding folders.

**BUT**

Although it's clear there, that the folders are included with ItemCount, but not for Items.Count, there is another more subtle difference - if you are running code in a user context, you will see that the Items collection is security- trimmed, and its count is therefore only for those items the user can see.  On the other hand, ItemCount does not appear to be security trimmed.

**ALSO**

ItemCount is faster because it gets a static SPList property instead of building the SPListItemCollection object before counting its members.

**Reference**

[SPList.ItemCount is not the same as SPList.Items.Count](https://www.1stquad.com/sharepoint-kompetenz-erfahrung-know-how/blog/default/november-2012/splist-itemcount-not-same-as-splist-items-count)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the item collection is security trimmed, very important to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

`$list.itemcount` counts the folders also

while `$items.count` counts the list items